# capacirif soil moisture sensor

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-analysis, sensor, connector, interface

[image]

I am in the process of creating an electronic circuit for a capacitive soil moisture sensor with an Op-Amp to amplify the sensor output signal, and this sensor connects with the attiny85 micro-controller which also includes 2 interfaces, one for programming, for which I use the 6 pin ISP connector and the other for I2C communication, for which I use a 4 pin connector.can you help me, this is my circuit for a solution for a capacitive soil moisture sensor connected with attiny85 which connects itself with two connectors for two interfaces one for I2C communication which is 4 pins and the other for the programming interface which is 6 pins, are there any proposals to reduce the number of connectors or are there any connectors that are not usable in this circuit?

Comment: Ayda Benayed - Hi, This appears to be a duplicate of your [previous question](/q/706233). Please do not repeat the same question.